# update service parameter with data from another service

Tags: angularjs

I have this service:

```
 footballdataAPI.getTeam = function(id) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = '613a6b6937394ae8a94d69f358f76902';
        return $http.get('http://www.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/398/fixtures?matchday=5?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
    };
```

However I'd like to update the parameter of matchday when data is updated on another service specifically here, ie grab the matchday of within this json callback and use it in that other service automatically. Not sure how to go about it, any ideas?

**SERVICE**

```
footballdataAPI.getTeams = function() {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = '613a6b6937394ae8a94d69f358f76902';
            return $http.get('http://www.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/398/leagueTable?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
        };
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
  .controller('teamsController', function($scope,   footballdataAPIservice) {
    $scope.teamsList = [];
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="secondary-title">Matchday {{teamsList.matchday}}</h2>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  are you asking how to pass `matchday=id` instead of `matchday=5` in your service call? how does the second service listed relate to the first? and where are you calling either one of these services?

Comment: @Claies yes exactly, i want to pass matchday=id